# Alignment issues with histogram2d and pcolormesh

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize a histogram with color as the "3rd dimension".

Here is my code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    x=[1,2,3,4,5]
    y=[4,4,4,4,4]
    z=[1,2,3,4,5]
    x=np.array(x)
    y=np.array(y)
    z=np.array(z)
    hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, weights=z)
    counts, _, _ = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(xedges, yedges))

    average = hist/counts

    plt.pcolormesh(average)
    plt.colorbar()
```

My result

[image: My results]

I am confused about why the boxes of colors are not correctly corresponding to the x and y arrays? For example, the yellow box should be located vertically at 5, not at 10.

Answer (score 0):

`np.histogram2d` defaults to `bins=10`. That is, you have `10` bins in each direction. So your `xedges,yedges` are of length 11, and `hist` and `count` are `11x11` array. Therefore, `pcolormesh` shows a `11x11` picture, and the top values `10` of the y-axis corresponds to `xedges[-1]` which is `5`.

Comment: Thank you! Another question, when I make this my code: import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[1,5,7,4,9]
z=[1,2,3,4,5]
x=np.array(x)
y=np.array(y)
z=np.array(z)
hist, yedges, xedges = np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=[20,10], weights=z)
counts, _, _ = np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=(yedges, xedges))

average = hist/counts

plt.pcolormesh(average)
plt.colorbar()

The y axis now goes to 20 instead of 10. How do I change the numbers on the axes?

Comment: please don't put code in comment, you can edit your question with the updated code.

Comment: But yes, you specifically force 20 bins in y by `np.histogram2d(y, x, bins=[20,10], weights=z) `

Comment: I apologize. But my question is, how do I specify the numbers on the x and y axis without changing the number of bins?

Comment: If you want to change bins, but you want the label on the axes the actual value, try `plt.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges, average)`